# Why does my keyboard malfunction? And what can be done to fix it?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I recently bought a new laptop, but I'm encountering some perplexing issues with the keyboard. Here's a breakdown of the problems:

1. **Random Character Inputs**: The keyboard sporadically inputs characters like `!5"I6#]J7$q^K8%¦r_L9&` without any manual input, occurring at unpredictable intervals.
2. **Repetitive Inputs on <kbd>P</kbd> and <kbd>R</kbd> Key**: Pressing the <kbd>P</kbd> and <kbd>R</kbd> key results in repetitive inputs of `0[;o0-'l9[-'l9;-'l9o-'l9` and triggers the <kbd>Winkey</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> combination after 1-3 seconds or when 2-5 other keys are pressed.
3. **Erratic Inputs on <kbd>M</kbd> and <kbd>T</kbd> Key**: Inputting on the <kbd>M</kbd> and <kbd>T</kbd> key leads to erratic character strings like `, njk h, kh jn,kh ,mnbvcxz./bc.,z`' and activates <kbd>Del</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> after 1-3 seconds or when 2-5 other keys are pressed.
4. **Random Key Presses**: The keyboard occasionally registers multiple random actions, including power button, middle button, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Fn</kbd>, <kbd>Winkey</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Menu</kbd>, <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> keys, and <kbd>8</kbd> on the <kbd>spacebar</kbd> after 1-3 seconds or when 2-5 other keys are pressed.
5. **Unpredictable Responses with <kbd>X</kbd> Key**: Pressing the <kbd>X</kbd> key sporadically results in registering either `CS` or `DA`, followed by delayed inputs of <kbd>Z</kbd> or the <kbd>spacebar</kbd>, and eventually <kbd>Winkey</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> or `2 F2` at random times.
6. **Inconsistent Behavior after Specific Key Inputs**: After pressing keys like <kbd>]</kbd>, <kbd>/</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, or <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the keyboard behaves unexpectedly, simulating the <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Pg Up</kbd>, <kbd>Pg Dn</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>PrtScr</kbd>, and <kbd>Tab</kbd> functions at random intervals.

These keyboard errors are quite frustrating and affecting my work.

Typing input animation

[image]

---

**Update**: Trigger occurs after 1-3 seconds random exposure or press other key before 3-5 clicks.

[image]

Comment: 1. " I recently purchased a new laptop..." Return it. 2. The issue indicates something pressing on the keyboard, e.g., a swelled battery. **If** that is the cause, it's a fire hazard.

Comment: What @DrMoishePippik said. Your laptop is new: You should be relying on the warranty/return policy at this point. Especially hardware related issues, like this one, can be evidence of poor build controls and likely indicate other still-invisible issues.